# Non-matching values for modulus and p*q in RSA encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, biginteger, multiplication

I am currently doing a cryptography project which involves RSA encryption. I used the RSACryptoServiceProvider class to generate the values p, q and n (modulus). Since n = p*q, I decided to test if the two values (i.e. p*q and n) match. When I used the BigInteger class to multiply p and q I got a different answer compared to the n as generated from the RSACryptoServiceProvider class. The code is shown below:

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        //export rsa parameters i.e. p , q , e and d
        RSAParameters rsaparams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
        //set the p parameter
        byte[] p = rsaparams.P;
        Array.Reverse(p);
        BigInteger primeP = new BigInteger(p);

        //set the Q parameter
        byte[] q = rsaparams.Q;
        Array.Reverse(q);
        BigInteger primeQ = new BigInteger(q);

        //set the d parameter
        byte[] d = rsaparams.D;
        Array.Reverse(d);
        BigInteger privexponent = new BigInteger(d);

        //set the e parameter
        byte[] e = rsaparams.Exponent;
        Array.Reverse(e);
        BigInteger pubexponent = new BigInteger(e);

        //set the m parameter
        byte[] m = rsaparams.Modulus;
        Array.Reverse(m);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(m);


        Console.WriteLine("p:\n{0}\n", primeP);
        Console.WriteLine("q:\n{0}\n", primeQ);
        Console.WriteLine("modulus:\n{0}\n", modulus);
        Console.WriteLine();

        //perform multiplication of p and q manually
        Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Multiply(primeP, primeQ));
```

Is there a way of fixing this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that reversing the arrays is not enough. Because they are unsigned they also require padding depending on the value at the end of the array.

If the value at the end of the array is >= 128 the high bit of that value is set and the `byte[]` constructor for `BigInteger` interprets this as a negative sign. Tacking on a 0 in this case prevents this.

```
public static BigInteger FromBigEndian(byte[] p)
{
    var q = p.Reverse();
    return new BigInteger((p[0] < 128 ? q : q.Concat(new byte[] { 0 })).ToArray());
}
```

Convert parameters as follows instead

```
byte[] p = rsaparams.P;
BigInteger primeP = FromBigEndian(p);
```